# Rename .txt files to first line in file and add "()" to duplicates

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to rename 200+ `.txt` files in a directory with first line of their contents. The files contains IP address in format such as `12.345.678.90`. I have found a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which does exactly that, except that the duplicates don't get renamed at all.

I have edited *(to my needs)*, and tested following script on Server2016 and Windows10 Which renames the files but doesn't do anything for duplicates.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Multi-thread file rename program
if "%1" equ "Thread" goto ProcessBlock

rem Create the list of file names and count they
cd C:\Renamed_Files
set numFiles=0
(for %%f in (*.txt) do (
        echo %%f
        set /A numFiles+=1
)) > fileNames.tmp

rem Get number of threads and size of each block
set numThreads=%1
if not defined numThreads (
    set /A numThreads=1, blockSize=numFiles
) else (
    set /A blockSize=numFiles/numThreads
)

rem Create asynchronous threads to process block number 2 up to numThreads
if exist thread.* del thread.*
for /L %%t in (2,1,%numThreads%) do (
    echo %time% > thread.%%t
    start "" /B "%~F0" Thread %%t
)

rem Process block number 1
set count=0
for /F "delims=" %%f in (fileNames.tmp) do (
    set /p line1=<%%f
    ren "%%f" "!line1:~0,40!.txt"
    set /A count+=1
    if !count! equ %blockSize% goto endFirstBlock
)

:endFirstBlock

rem Wait for all asynchronous threads to end
if exist thread.* goto endFirstBlock

rem Delete the auxiliary file and end
del fileNames.tmp
goto :EOF


rem Process blocks 2 and up (asynchronous thread)

:ProcessBlock 
set /A skip=(%2-1)*blockSize, count=0
for /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%f in (fileNames.tmp) do (
    set /p line1=<%%f
    ren "%%f" "!line1:~0,40!.txt"
    set /A count+=1
    if !count! equ %blockSize% goto endBlock
)
:endBlock
del thread.%2
exit
```

I am hoping to rename `.txt` files and add `()` with a number of duplication so the duplicates can still get renamed with the same batch file, *(by editing it of course)*, or a new batch would be needed? any suggestion? or new code is welcome.

Eventually duplicate files can be merged in to one, (as they would be containing the same ip addresses anyway), and then renamed the file to their first line of the content.

Comment: Your question is too broad, we expect a [mcve] of your code and a single specific issue with it, you require assistance with. However your code doesn't exhibit an issue, it works. What you appear to be asking for is somebody to effectively provide you with the code to add functionality to someone else's script. That isn't how StackOverflow works. There are questions already on this site asking for how to copy/move/rename with duplicates receiving incremented numbers. Please search, implement what you learn, and then update your post with the information and new code to make it on topic.

Comment: When you joined up, you should have taken the [tour], and certainly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and all of its related links, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Compo i apologies if i have done something which is not how things works. I was following the guide lines when posting the question and one of the guideline was to provide with a code which has been tested so i placed the code in it. As i mentioned earlier that i am trying to automate a process with script and task scheduler. With my 2 days search i have found only one code that has worked after editing it to solve the half of what i want to acheive. just asking for guidelines and a code to solve the issue duplication with duplication. and whether it is achievable with a simple script?

Comment: As you stated, **_just asking for guidelines and a code_**, unfortunately we are not a provider of code, just a fixer of it, and, as I've already stated, your code doesn't exhibit an issue and therefore doesn't require fixing. What we expect you to do is to search this site and elsewhere for any code which performs a `copy`/`move`/`rename` task, take the methodolgy used and integrate it into your existing code. If it then doesn't work, you'll be able to post code which requires fixing, and therefore have an on topic question.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple threads, you might have a race condition leading to a collision.  The way I would *start* this is to use the thread number to avoid collisions.  I am showing untested example code.  Due to the difficulties with parentheses in DOS, I am instead going to use periods and recommend the same to you:

```
...

:ProcessBlock 
set /A skip=(%2-1)*blockSize, count=0
for /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%f in (fileNames.tmp) do call :ProcessBlockLoop "%%~f" %2
goto :eof

:ProcessBlockLoop
set /p line1=<"%~1"
set "filename=!line1:~0,40!"

:: Check for an existing file.
if not exist "%filename%.txt" goto :ProcessBlockLoopContinue

:: if we get here then there is an existing file.
set DupCnt=1

:ProcessBlockFilenameLoop

if not exist "%filename%.%2.%DupCnt%.txt" (
   set filename=%filename%.%2.%DupCnt%
   goto :ProcessBlockLoopContinue
)
:: increment our duplicate counter and try again
set /a DupCnt += 1
goto :ProcessBlockFilenameLoop


:ProcessBlockLoopContinue
:: Try the rename.  If the rename fails, then reset the variables and loop again.
:: A retry counter should be added to avoid an infinite loop.
ren "%%f" "%filename%.txt" || set DupCnt=1&&set "filename=!line1:~0,40!"&&goto :ProcessBlockFilenameLoop

:: If we're here, the rename should have worked.  You could double check again if desired.
set /A count+=1
if %count% equ %blockSize% (
   del thread.%2
   exit
)
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for response it is much appreciated. Please consider me as noob in coding. i am unable to understand what you are suggesting with the code provided.

Comment: Can the person who wrote the original batch file help you?  I wouldn't consider this code to be any more difficult than the original code this is being added to.  And I have inline comments to show what is being done.